# flask cache delete_many error

Tags: flask, flask-cache

I'm not good at flask and a naturally django developer I was forced to because it is already developed..

May question is how to use delete_many using flask-cache

```
cache.delete_many(["sample_4", "sample_5"])
```

This returns an error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

I'm aware that this is the right way, but what I want is a list of keys as a parameter to be deleted

```
cache.delete_many("sample_3", "sample_2")
```

I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `delete_many` with arguments unpacked from a list

```
cache.delete_many(*["sample_4", "sample_5"])
```